# Validation Message Filter Search Angular

Tags: angularjs, validation, filter

I want to display a message if no element found in my list.
And if the item is found, the message is no longer displayed.
How am I going to do for this?
Here is my example:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xvY0unv344BEP7rR12TZ?p=preview)

```html
  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      <h3>Filter by String</h3>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input ng-model="match.name" type="text" placeholder="Filter by name" autofocus>
      </form>
      <ul ng-repeat="friend in friends | exact: match | orderBy: 'name' ">
        <li>{{friend.name}} ({{friend.age}})</li>
      </ul>

    <div>pas d'élement trouvé dans la liste</div>

    </div>

  </body>
```

I want to show "pas d'élémént trouvé ..." if 0 found in my list

Controller code :

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    { name: "Peter",   age: 20 },
    { name: "Pablo",   age: 55 },
    { name: "Linda",   age: 20 },
    { name: "Marta",   age: 37 },
    { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
    { name: "Markus",  age: 32 }
  ];

  $scope.filterFunction = function(element) {
    return element.name.match(/^Ma/) ? true : false;
  };

})

app.filter('exact', function(){
  return function(items, match){
    var matching = [], matches, falsely = true;
    
    // Return the items unchanged if all filtering attributes are falsy
    angular.forEach(match, function(value, key){
      falsely = falsely && !value;
    });
    if(falsely){
      return items;
    }
    
    angular.forEach(items, function(item){ // e.g. { title: "ball" }
      matches = true;
      angular.forEach(match, function(value, key){ // e.g. 'all', 'title'
        if(!!value){ // do not compare if value is empty
          matches = matches && (item[key] === value);  
        }
      });
      if(matches){
        matching.push(item);  
      }
    });
    return matching;
  }
});
```

thanks

Comment: Can you paste your controller code here ??

Comment: Controller code in my Edited question . Code complet : http://plnkr.co/edit/xvY0unv344BEP7rR12TZ?p=preview

Comment: why it doesnt Work if I search  the filter by matricule : http://plnkr.co/edit/azo7v0EiW889MdYv86fg?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vxsQsH6BYKHS8zYhIP4Q?p=preview)

You can save your filtered list to any variable and check this variable to see whether is there any list available after the filtering.

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in (result = (friends | exact: match | orderBy: 'name') ) ">
        <li>{{friend.name}} ({{friend.age}})</li>
</ul>
<p ng-show="result.length == 0"> Not Found </p>
```

Comment: why it doesnt Work if I search the filter by matricule : plnkr.co/edit/azo7v0EiW889MdYv86fg?p=preview

Comment: yes like this , but i want to have exact value. For example if input =P , result = not found

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable in your controller as `$scope.isListPresent = $scope.friends.length > 0;` and based on this variable you can put a `ng-if` on your message `div` as below -

```
<div ng-show="!isListPresent">pas d'élement trouvé dans la liste</div>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: If this works he might aswell just use ng-if="friends.length == 0"

Comment: Btw, it should be $scope.friends.length in the controller

Comment: yep... this code was added before the controller code ... :P